# Аккардеон растягивает фон

Tags: jquery, css3, html5, адаптивная-верстка

Суть вопроса в том что имеется допустим такой вот сайт https://balakleenko.ru/faq.html у которого на данной странице прикручен аккордеон. Но при раскрытие он удлиняет тело сайта и за ним тянется фон. Возможно ли сделать чтобы фон оставался неподвижен ?

Answer (score 1):

Не используйте `background-size` (класс `.bg`) для таких целей. По оси y вы выставляете 100%, соответственно фон растягивается на всю высоту блока.

Если совсем уж безвыходная ситуация, то можно прописать так

```
background-size: 100vw 100vh;
```

Или использовать только ось x (тогда и картинку не будет плющить):

```
background-size: 100%;
```

Comment: 100vh - это длина видимой области, потому у меня и указано 100% чтобы он ( фон ) до низу тянулся. А отсутствия background-size для Y к сожалению не дает никакого результата ((.

Comment: @МихаилБалаклеенко Вот он и тянется до низу всегда, даже при увеличении блока. Как не даёт? Всё нормально должно быть (https://i.imgur.com/2Yky8yG.png)

Comment: Возможно вы не правильно поняли задачу. Вопрос в том что фон должен быть на всю длину сайта а соответственно 100vh не подойдет т.к. ниже края экрана фона не будет на странице. Тоже касается не указания по высоте background-size. То есть мне нужно было чтобы фон был на всю длину но не увеличивался при раскрытии аккордеона. Решил проблему подложив div c фоном под контент указав ему абсолют и высоту в 3500 px c повтором по высоте. В любом случае спасибо за совет. Вероятно я просто не верно изложил задачу.